# sql query to create a table at runtime and insert the values in it from the select statement from the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

what i am tryin to do is make a table(@tbl) runtime and insert the data from the select statement from the database,as what i have done so far is

```
 declare @tbl TABLE (
      Item          int
)   

begin

insert into @tbl values    select cid  from tbl_custumer  where cus_ph like '%'+'987'+'%'
select * from @tbl  
end
```

as "select cid" statement returns multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want the code to look like this:

```
begin
    declare @tbl TABLE (
          Item int
    ); 

    insert into @tbl(Item) 
        select cid
        from tbl_custumer 
        where cus_ph like '%'+'987'+'%';

    select *
    from @tbl;
end;
```

Notes:

- The `begin`/`end` block is not really necessary, but I'm guessing you want it for other reasons (a stored procedure, `if`, or something similar).
- The `values` keyword is not needed when using `insert . . . select`.
- Use semicolons at the end of each SQL statement.  Although they are optional, they make the code easier to follow.

Comment: this is the solution thanx sir